# I can't connect to Microsoft SQL Server through Java

Tags: java, sql-server, docker, ssl

I have SQL Server installed through Docker on Windows and I can connect to the database with VS Code through the SQL Server extension, but I can't get it to connect in my Java code. I get the error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not
> establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets
> Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target".
> ClientConnectionId:018acf50-eefc-41e8-842a-6b7ef89a84d9

I installed the JDBC driver through Maven:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.2.jre17</version>
</dependency>
```

The code:

```java
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConnectToMSSQL {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Set connection parameters.
        String hostName = "localhost";
        String dbName = "testdb";
        String user = "SA";
        String password = "<password>";
        String url = String.format("jdbc:sqlserver://%s;databaseName=%s;user=%s;password=%s", hostName, dbName, user, password);

        // Connect to the database.
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url)) {
            System.out.println("Connection established.");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection failed.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error means that the SQL Server instance uses a self-signed certificate, or a certificate signed by a CA which is not known to Java. As a result, the certificate is not trusted, and the connection will be rejected. You need to import the certificate (or the CA certificate) into the truststore of your JVM, or configure the JDBC driver to not validate the certificate (I don't know if that is possible or not).

Comment: The [Connecting with encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-with-ssl-encryption?view=sql-server-ver16) documentation from Microsoft suggests you should use `trustServerCertificate=true` as a connection property.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel adding trustServerCertificate=true solved it, thank you!

Comment: For what it's worth this has been the case since [JDBC Driver 10.2 for SQL Server Released](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/jdbc-driver-10-2-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3100754) due to its breaking change, _Encrypt = true, by default_.